# How to use NSPredicate in NSexpression subquery

Tags: swift

How to get @sum.amount at once request which type == 0 and type == 1

it's parameter look like blow:

```
------------------------
|date    | Date()      |
------------------------
|type    | Int (0 or 1)|
------------------------
|amount  | Double      |
------------------------
```

```
let countExp = NSExpressionDescription()
countExp.expressionResultType = .integer32AttributeType
countExp.name = "count"
countExp.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "date")])

let expendSumExp = NSExpressionDescription()
expendSumExp.expressionResultType = .doubleAttributeType
expendSumExp.name = "expendSum"
expendSumExp.expression = NSExpression(forSubquery: NSExpression(format: "@sum.amount"),usingIteratorVariable: "x",predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == 0", #keyPath(Record.type)))

let incomeSumExp = NSExpressionDescription()
incomeSumExp.expressionResultType = .doubleAttributeType
incomeSumExp.name = "incomeSum"
incomeSumExp.expression = NSExpression(forSubquery: NSExpression(format: "@sum.amount"),usingIteratorVariable: "x",predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == 1", #keyPath(Record.type)))

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "Record")
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["date"]
request.propertiesToFetch = ["date", countExp, expendSum, incomeSum]
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K BETWEEN {%@, %@}", #keyPath(Record.date), startDate, endDate)
```

I expect get a result dictionary is

```
[
{
 date: 2019-08-02,
 count: 10,
 expendSum: 200,
 incomeSum: 150
},
{
 date: 2019-08-01,
 count: 9,
 expendSum: 300,
 incomeSum: 50
},
.....
]
```

but expendSumExp and incomeSumExp is wrong in predicate.

Comment: I'm interested in what you've been trying to achieve. Have you made it work? Could you post a solution? Thanks!